# Material2 slider component with flexible step values

Tags: angular, slider

By going through material2 slider component [documentation](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/slider/README.md), I defined a slider component.

With the below slider component definition

```
<md-slider min="1" max="20" step="5" value="1"></md-slider>
```

we can select one of the below values.

1, 6, 11, 16, 20.

0 being the invalid value, is there any way we can define the slider component so that we can select one of the below values?

1, 5, 10, 15, 20.

Comment: would also want to know if this is possible. Seems stepsArray would be a great if there's way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default min value to 0.
set min=0 for default case.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something with initial value.
set it as 1, initial value sets the handler at at specified value on initialization.